# How to test function which returns function with parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I want to test the code below, but i'm unsure how to test this function since it returns a function with parameters. You can see in the image that i'm trying to achieve 100% test coverage and to do that I need a test that gets into the returned function.

```
const jwt = require('express-jwt')

function validateJwt (tokenConfig) {
  if (!tokenConfig || !tokenConfig.secret) {
    throw new TypeError('tokenConfig param must be defined and have attribute "secret"')
  }

  return (req, res, next) => {
    jwt(_.extend({}, tokenConfig, {
      requestProperty: 'tkn',
      getToken: ReqHelpers.getEitherTkn
    }))
  }
}
```

Test method which obviously fails with the error `AssertionError: expected [Function] to be true`

```
it('should succeed', () => {
  let result = middleware.validateJwt({secret: 'foo'})
  expect(result).to.be.true
})
```

[image]

Comment: well, result will be a function, so, you'd need to call it I guess - except of course, the function returned by `validateJwt` is a function that will only ever return `undefined` anyway, so your test will always fail regardless

Comment: Why not invert it, expect it not to throw an error?

Comment: It seems like you need to call it, get the returned function and then execute a test with the returned function (probably mocking it's arguments) so you can see if the returned function does what it's supposed to when it is executed.

Comment: What I don't understand is the returned function looks like it would be Express middleware, but it doesn't operate on `req`, `res` or call `next()` so it doesn't seem like it's valid middleware.

Comment: @jfriend00 it is express middleware and there's magic in the `jwt()` function which comes from here https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt

Comment: It just doesn't seem like `validateJwt()` is written properly.  It seems like it needs to do `return jwt(...)`, not `return (req, res, next) => { jwt() }`.  `jwt()` returns a middleware function directly and you need that function to be called.  Your `validateJwt()` won't call that function, in fact it ignores that returned middleware function.

Comment: No i absolutely want the method called this way. It allows me to pass a parameter to the function to be used, yet still returns a function with the signature that express middleware needs (which is function(req, res, next))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of test, what we can do is to spy on jwt function call and checking its arguments.

**Updated:**

since `express-jwt` return function, we need to involve `proxyquire` to spy the function. Ref: https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire

You can do something like this:

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const jwtSpy = sinon.spy();
const middleware = proxyquire('./middleware', { 'express-jwt': jwtSpy }); // 'express-jwt' comes from your require statement for this package

it('should call jwt', () => {
  const req = sinon.spy();
  const res = sinon.spy();
  const next = sinon.spy();  

  middleware.validateJwt({secret: 'foo'})(req, res, next);

  expect(jwtSpy.called).to.be.ok;
  expect(jwtSpy.calledWithArg({ secret: 'foo', requestProperty: 'tkn'}).to.be.ok; // for checking the arguments
})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm not following how `sinon.spy(something, 'jwt')` is supposed to work with my given function since jwt isn't a property of "something".

Comment: Looks like that will work, although i was really hoping to not having to bring in proxyquire and write a test just using sinon if possible.

Comment: @Catfish yeah I wish I could just use Sinon too. This is because of jwt. Another alternative maybe you can create an abstraction module for this jwt and we you use that module in your code then we can test just it just using Sinon.

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is to inject the jwt method by passing it into the method. That would allow me to simply use sinon to test, but hinders the consumer use of `validateJwt`

Answer (score 0):

Right, so two things.

First, in your test you need to execute the returned function rather than testing it directly. Unfortunately I’m on my phone and can’t post code right now.

Second, your function that’s returned doesn’t return anything itself, as it just calls the jwt function. This isn’t necessarily a problem. As long as jwt() is updating some object or variable in your test space, you can test the current state of that obj/variable in your test instead of interrogating the function directly.

Comment: I believe internally `jwt()` does call the `next()`. How am i supposed to test the returned function though?